# Detecting ADB Debugging in Tasker

Tags: android, adb, tasker

I am trying to create a tasker profile that tells my tablet to leave the screen on, as long as my computer is connected to it via adb. The only problem is, that I don't know how to check whether my tablet is connected to adb using tasker. I connect adb to my tablet using wifi, so detecting USB connection changes on my tablet is no option. I already tried reading the USB-debugging setting using a Java function found in the Settings.Global class, but that only gave me information about whether the USB debugging setting is enabled in my developer settings, and not whether my tablet is currently connected to adb. Thanks for your help!

Comment: does the tablet show notification when being remotely debugged (as it does when USB-debugging is active)?

Comment: Hi, no nothing changes visually on the device.